# wordpress/woocommerce make the 'theme_location' for pulling a menu equal the page title ID.

Tags: php, html, wordpress, menu, woocommerce

I want to insert a menu in my archive-product.php, however, I want this menu to be unique for every product page. I plan on accomplishing this by defining the menu name with the same name as the page title or page ID in woocommerce for my custom theme. and then setting my `'theme_location' => 'insert page title here'` to equal the page title dynamically.

Currently in the archive-product.php I placed this code:

```
<?php

                $args = array(
                    'theme_location' => '<?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?>'
                );

                ?>

                <?php wp_nav_menu(  $args ); ?>
```

obviously `'<?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?>'`  does not workdue to it being wrapped in single quotes. Is there any argument I can use to return the value of the page title? I've tried `<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>`  as well, however, same story; it is PHP wrapped inside single quotes which is seen as a text string instead code.

PS I am receptive to different methods to accomplishing this goal if this approach is simply not optimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your problem are the quotes, just call it with "false" as parameter, and it will return the page title instead of echoing it. So you will have:

```
'theme_location' => woocommerce_page_title(false)
```

http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/function-woocommerce_page_title.html

But if I were you, i'd register in functions.php all my sidebars dynamically. First, use get_posts() to fetch all the pages, then foreach page grab its title and register a sidebar with that title.